# Hide Navigation Bar on one view controller, show it on the pushed one

Tags: iphone, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have searched a lot but didn't find a solution to my problem.
I have a search bar on my root view controller. When I select it, my keypad appears and I hide (animated) the navigation bar. Now, when I press on one cell, I push a new view controller.The problem is that when I show the navigation bar, it doesn't look natural, it comes from the top, and the pushed view controller comes from the right. I want to do something similar to the email application: the pushed view controller and the navigation bar to come together from the right.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know if this is right approach, but may be they push new NavigationController?

Comment: I tried, but you can't put a Navigation Controller inside another Navigation Controller, I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the navigation bar visible in **ViewController A** (with Navbar hidden) like this:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
}
```

and in **ViewController B** you need to write this code in the ViewDidLoad or ViewWillLoad:

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

that's working for me, hope this can help.